# Drawing a circle and high definition

Tags: android

In most of the android applications, the border of the circles are beautiful and the pixels in part of border of the circles are monotonic and beautiful. But when I draw a circle using the following code and when I see the result in my device, the pixels in part of border of the circle is like bitten apple.Such as when an ant has eaten around an apple.

**My Code:**

```
class Circle extends View {
Paint paint;
Circle(Context context) {
super(context);
paint = new Paint();
}
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
canvas.drawCircle(50,50,30,paint);
}
}
```

Comment: What you want is to make "anti-aliasing". Search for "anti-aliasing" in polygons in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on antialiasing to achieve it:

```
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this demo [How to draw a circle in Android](http://alvinalexander.com/android/how-to-draw-circle-in-android-view-ondraw-canvas)
set [ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG) flag true

For more info you may visit:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html